# Searching for a value in Excel from two columns in different worksheets, returning yes or no

Tags: excel, worksheet-function

I have one workbook, with two separate worksheets. I want to know if the values that appear in worksheet B also appear in worksheet A, if so, I want to return a "YES". If not, I want to return a "NO". Based on columns A and B.

Example:
 Worksheet A is a list of Students enrolled in certain programs. Worksheet B is the entire school.

In worksheet A, I have the following data set:

```
   NAME             DOB
1  Bob Builder   1/1/2001 
2  Patrik Str    2/2/2001
3  Thunder Ct    3/3/2001
4  peter Grif    4/4/2001
```

In worksheet B, I have the following data set:

```
   NAME            DOB
1  Bob Builder   1/1/2001 
2  Patrik Str    2/2/2001
3  Thunder Ct    3/3/2001
4  peter Grif    4/4/2001
5  Bob Builder   8/8/2011 
6  Patrik Str    2/25/2001
```

I have tried `=IFERROR(IF(MATCH(A1,Sheet1!$A:$A,0),"yes",),"no")` but it is only looking for column A not B. This works fine only because it looks at column A but there are also other students that have the same name but different DOB.

can Match contain two columns for comparison ?

Comment: you can add the second condition like iferror(if (match(val1&val2,range1&range2),"Yes"),"no").... also you might need to commit this as an array formula

Answer (score 0):

Try in cell D2: `=If(C2=(Index(Sheet1!$C:$C,Match(B2,Sheet1!$B:$B))),"yes","no")`